# Entity Framework 6.1 How to update objects when database changes?

Tags: entity-framework

I used the "Code First From Database" option in Entity Framework 6.1.0 to generate objects based on an existing database. I now realize that I need to make a few changes to that database.

Once I have made these changes, I obviously want them to be reflected in the objects I generated using Entity Framework 6.1.0. I don't see a way to do a refresh or anything like that. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you looking for [Code-First Data Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591621.aspx)?

Comment: Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907

Comment: Thanks guys. I think I started down the wrong path. I think what I want to do is design the database using the "Empty EF Designer model" instead of designing it first in SQL.

Comment: If you want to use code first you have to make your changes in the code and EF will generate migration SQL statements for you to update the Database. If you want to make changes in database that are then are reflected in your code use database first.